# Removing word from string if condition is met?

Tags: python, string

I need to do some "cleaning" on a series of strings. 
1. Special characters to be removed (like !@#$%^ etc)
2. All words in the string should be in small letters
3. remove words if the word is <= 2 characters. ("a, it, me, us" etc)

```
trainset = [('It is too bad that our jane is just a pigeon. It would be great if it could speak. It would be able to prove my innocence.'), ('I have no other choice. Is death the only way to prove it? Loving you is really hard!'), ('These are my last words.')]

def cleanedthings(trainset):
cleanedtrain = []
specialch = "!@#$%^&*-=_+:;\".,/?`~][}{|)("
for line in trainset:
    for word in line.split():
        lowword = word.lower()
        for ch in specialch:
            if ch in lowword:
                lowword = lowword.replace(ch,"")
        if len(lowword) >= 3:
            cleanedtrain.append(lowword)
return cleanedtrain
```

The above function doesn't seem to be working.. Can you help me? And also, I need the final output to be in a string format, rather than a list format.

Comment: Hi, your code is not properly indented, and thus cannot work

Comment: My question is about the logic of the code, rather than the bugs of the code... thanks for your answer though. @AnttiHaapala

Comment: Whitespace is syntactically relevant in *Python*, and therefore can affect logic, so it's important that the code is indented here exactly as it is for you.

Comment: Out of curiosity. is your code running without error ?

Comment: Also, if you are doing natural language processing, then the NLTK natural language processor can do word tokenizing pretty effortlessly with [nltk.tokenize.regexp.RegexpTokenizer](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#module-nltk.tokenize.regexp).

Comment: As a side note, that `if ch in lowword:` check isn't doing anything. Just call `lowword = lowword.replace(ch, '')`; if it's not present, nothing will get changed. If you're worried about it being slower, (a) it's almost certainly not a performance bottleneck in your code, and (b) it's probably actually faster. (If `ch` is present, you only have to scan the string once instead of twice; if `ch` is not present, `replace` is doing basically the same scan as `in`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check indentation and syntax. Logic is fine.

```
trainset = [('It is too bad that our jane is just a pigeon. It would be great if it could speak. It would be able to prove my innocence.'), ('I have no other choice. Is death the only way to prove it? Loving you is really hard!'), ('These are my last words.')]

def cleanedthings(trainset):
    cleanedtrain = []
    specialch = "!@#$%^&*-=_+:;\".,/?`~][}{|)("
    for line in trainset:
        for word in line.split():
            lowword = word.lower()
            for ch in specialch:
                if ch in lowword:
                    lowword = lowword.replace(ch,"")
            if len(lowword) >= 3:
                cleanedtrain.append(lowword)
    return cleanedtrain

print " ".join(cleanedthings(trainset))
```

Comment: Okay thanks for correcting my indentation! The last line of your code is just what I needed. Thanks!